# Non-static member initializers for non-integers not working in GCC 4.8?

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc4.8

Trying to compile the following code in GCC 4.8:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<class T>
class Bar {
public:
    std::string test = "test";
};

int main() {
    Bar<int> bar;
    return 0;
}
```

Using `g++ --std=c++11 -o main main.cpp` gives the following error:

```
main.cpp: In constructor ‘constexpr Bar<int>::Bar()’:
main.cpp:5:7: error: conversion from ‘const char [5]’ to non-scalar type ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ requested
 class Bar {
       ^
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:11:14: note: synthesized method ‘constexpr Bar<int>::Bar()’ first required here
     Bar<int> bar;
              ^
```

However, it compiles correctly in the following cases:

- Using GCC 5.2
- Replacing `std::string` with `int` (and using an integer value on the right side)
- Not using a template class

Is it a bug in GCC 4.8? I can't find a way to install GCC 5.2 on my server (I need to compile it for CentOS 6.8) so I believe I'm stuck here.

Comment: yes gcc 4.8 doesn't support this. you are probably forced to use initialization list of just body of `Bar`'s constructor

Comment: I find it strange that it doesn't specifically support non-integer initializers in template classes, but works in other cases. I suppose I could write a constructor for that specific class (I think I only have one template class that requires such initialization), as long as it works in all other cases.

Comment: Does this `std::string test{"test};` or `std::string test = std::string("test");` work?

Comment: I think if you go "old good way" and either write `test = "test";` in constructor or `test("test")` in initialization list it will work everywhere

Comment: @mvidelgauz Of course it will, but I think that isn't the point here.

Comment: @riv It looks like a bug to me, but both options I mentioned in my first comment work with g++ 4.8.4 on ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Yes, I changed it to an initialization list and it works. It is kind of important for me to be able to use in-class initializers because I have a lot of automatically generated data type definitions that are supposed to be easily readable. Only one of them requires a template though, so its not a huge deal.

Comment: @juanchopanza: my actual case is a lot more complicated so it doesn't help, I'll just stick with initializer lists for this class, thanks.

Comment: @riv I can't imagine what complication would force you to use `foo x = bar;`  instead of `foo x{bar};`.